onResume begin called when app is in background on launch
On Android 14, If I'm launching an app while the device is locked, it will call onResume/onPause, while the app is in the background.  This is causing issues with NFC intent registration, because the NFC intents assume that onResume is called when the app goes into the foreground, but I'm getting an exception when registering the Intent because it is actually in the background.  What is the proper procedure for determining whether or not I can actually register this intent?
You can see from this thread dump that this is being called from Android's own invocation of onResume:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {MYPACKAGE.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Foreground dispatch can only be enabled/disabled when your activity is in foreground
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4963)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4996)
at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:57)
at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:180)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:98)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2444)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8223)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:977)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Foreground dispatch can only be enabled/disabled when your activity is in foreground
at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3065)
at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3041)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3024)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2966)
at android.nfc.INfcAdapter$Stub$Proxy.setForegroundDispatch(INfcAdapter.java:810)
at android.nfc.NfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(NfcAdapter.java:1487)
at MYPACKAGE.NfcUtil.registerForNfcIntents(NfcUtil.java:44)
at MYPACKAGE.onResume(BaseActivity.java:325)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1604)
at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:8743)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4953)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4996) 
at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:57) 
at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:180) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:98) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2444) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8223) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:977) 

On previous versions of Android this didn't happen.  I don't know if it wasn't calling onResume or if it was calling onResume but not caring that it wasn't in the foreground.

If you are able to reproduce this behavior on a Google Pixel with a sample project, it might be worth filing an issue, attaching that project.
